# How to fix gnu screen term detection when started on detached mode?

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm writing a script that spawns a `screen` process but depends on some pre-conditions I intend to perform before attaching to it.

I noticed that when started in detached mode it does not recognize the `$TERM`, but I do not want to hardcode it on `.screenrc`, and I did not find anyone with the same problem.

Here's my environment:

```
$ screen --version
Screen version 4.06.02 (GNU) 23-Oct-17
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Here you can see it works as expected:

```
$ screen -ADRS profile
$ echo $TERM
screen.xterm-256color
```

But if done this way it goes all wrong:

```
$ screen -dmS profile
# I will perform some stuff here, then:
$ screen -ADrS profile
# here you can notice the colors have gone
$ echo $TERM
screen
```

How can I spawn a detached `screen` but get the same `$TERM` behavior as it was in the first case, without hardcoding the term on `.screenrc`?

Comment: These look like the solution to your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799395/starting-screen-in-detached-mode-doesnt-source-environment.

Comment: @slm I see that is a similar question, if there was an acceptable answer it could help me, but unfortunately none of that is applicable to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are (were) looking for:

```
screen -dmS foo -T "screen.$TERM"
```

I'm not sure if this solution is entirely general, but it should work fine as long as the parent-scope $TERM is properly set.

Comment: Probably take out the `"screen."` part: there's no `"screen.xterm"` for instance.